# Borel Measures: Integral Approximation

Tags: integration, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

**Problem**

Given a locally compact Hausdorff space.

Consider a regular Borel measure in the sense:
$$\mu:\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}_+:\quad\mu(E)=\inf_{E\subseteq U}\mu(U)\quad\mu(U)=\sup_{K\subseteq U}\mu(K)\quad(\mu(K)<\infty)$$

Then one can approximate the measure of opens by functions:
$$\mu(U)=\sup\left\{\int h\mathrm{d}\mu:h\in\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega):\quad h\leq\chi_U\right\}$$
Does a similar approach work for compacta:
$$\mu(K)=\inf\left\{\int h\mathrm{d}\mu:h\in\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega):\quad\chi_K\leq h\right\}$$
*(I have the feeling this may fail.)*

**Attempt**

For the former one has by regularity:
$$m\leq\mu(U):\quad m\leq\mu(K)\leq\mu(U)\quad(K\subseteq U)$$
Applying Urysohn's lemma one finds:
$$h\in\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega):\quad\mu(K)=\int\chi_K\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\int h\mathrm{d}\mu\quad(h\leq\chi_U)$$

For the latter one regularity is more twisted.

Comment: Note that one can drop the restriction of positivity as: $h\in\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega)\implies h_\pm:=\frac12(h\pm|h|)\in\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a compact set $K$. As you point out, if $h \in \mathcal C_0(\Omega)$ and $\chi_K \le h$ then $$\mu(K) = \int \chi_K \, d\mu \le \int h \, d\mu$$ so that $$\mu(K) \le \inf \left\{ \int h \, d\mu :\ h \in \mathcal C_0(\Omega),\ \chi_K \le h\right\}.$$

On the other hand, let $U \supset K$ be open. Since there exists $h_0 \in \mathcal C_0(\Omega)$ satisfying $\chi_K \le h_0 \le \chi_U$ you have that 
$$
\inf \left\{ \int h \, d\mu :\ h \in \mathcal C_0(\Omega),\ \chi_K \le h\right\} \le \int h_0 \, d\mu \le \sup \left\{ \int h \, d\mu :\ h \in \mathcal C_0(\Omega),\  h \le \chi_U \right\},$$
i.e.,
$$\inf \left\{ \int h \, d\mu :\ h \in \mathcal C_0(\Omega),\ \chi_K \le h\right\} \le \mu(U).$$
Now take the infimum over all $U$ containing $K$:
$$\inf \left\{ \int h \, d\mu :\ h \in \mathcal C_0(\Omega),\ \chi_K \le h\right\} \le \mu(K).$$

Comment: I really like your answer as it brings it to the point! *(I dropped the positivity.)*